# VARIANT datatype of C++ into C#

Tags: c#, c++, type-conversion, variant

What is equivalent of the VARIANT datatype of C++ in C#?

I have code in C++ which uses the VARIANT datatype. How can I convert that code in C#?

Comment: Do you need to interop with C++ code or just convert code?

Comment: The direct equivalent is `object` as the type and `object.GetType()` as the "what's in the variant?" information, but that would make for really poor C# code. Context is important.

Comment: If you are using c# 4.0, you can use the `dynamic` datatype, but as @Jon said, this will make for poor c# code, since you circumvent type safty and compile-time checking.

Comment: Depending on what the variants might be, you should use the superclass of those objects. If the superclass is 'object', as stated above, this will probably lead to bad design.

Comment: Impossible to say without context.

Comment: Actually `variants` make quite poor C++ code as well, but that doesn't stop people from using it... In C++ I would re-engineer a variant to a template in 99% of the cases, which means I would attempt to redesign it to a generic in C#.

Comment: I've been working on that too the last days. `byte[] myVar = new byte[16];` is your VARIANT. It's nothing more than 16 bytes together that you can access in many different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question.

From C# 4, you can use *dynamic* to indicate that the type is known at run-time.

By my personal understanding, however, c++ requires the type known at compile time. Thus you might consider to use `object`, but `object` in C# is an existent type.

For the concept of **multi-type, single value** (AKA polymorphism) of VARIANT, you would not need to find a corresponding type in C#, just define your classes and interfaces. You can always reference an object as its interface which the class implements.

If you are porting the code, and to figure out a syntax that you can simply use in LHS and for the considering of the type is known at compile time, then use **var**.

Answer (score 10):

Well, there are actually two variant's in C++: boost::variant and COM variant. The solution follows more or less the same idea, but the former is more complex. I expect you mean to use the latter.

Let me first start by telling that this is something you just shouldn't use if possible. That said, this is how you do it :-)

**Variants and interop**

Variants are sometimes used in interop of if you need the byte representation to be the same.

If you're dealing with interop, make sure to check out the `VariantWrapper` class on MSDN and make it work like that.

**Variants and porting considerations**

Variants are mostly used in APIs, and usually like this:

```
void Foo(SomeEnum operation, Variant data);
```

The reason it's done like this in C++ is because there is no base `object` class and you therefore need something like this. The easiest way to port this is to change the signature to:

```
void Foo(SomeEnum operation, object data);
```

However, if you're porting anyway, you also seriously want to consider these two, since they are resolved at compile-time and can save you the big 'switch' that usually follows in method `Foo`:

```
void SomeOperation(int data);
void SomeOperation(float data);
// etc
```

**Variants and byte consistency**

In rare cases you need to manipulate the bytes themselves.

Essentially the variant is just a big union of value types wrapped in a single value type (struct). In C++, you can allocate a value type on the heap because a struct is the same as a class (well sort-of). How the value type is being used is just a bit important but more on that later.

Union simply means you are going to overlap all the data in memory. Notice how I explicitly noted value type above; for variant's this is basically what it's all about. This also gives us a way to test it - namely by checking another value in the struct.

The way to do this in C# is to use the `StructLayout` attribute in a value type, which basically works as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Variant
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Integer;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float Float;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public double Double;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Byte;
    // etc
}

// Check if it works - shouldn't print 0.
public class VariantTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Variant v = new Variant() { Integer = 2 };
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", v.Float);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

C++ variant's can also be stored on the heap as I noted earlier. If you do this, you probably still want the memory signature to be the same. The way to do this is to box the Variant struct we build earlier by simply casing it to `object`.

Answer (score 2):

When **.NET implements a COM interface**, just **use VARIANT*** instead.

Then **bypass marshalling** on the .NET receiving side by using a **IntPtr** type to receive the pointer.

```
public class ComVariant
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Variant
    {
        public ushort vt;
        public ushort wReserved1;
        public ushort wReserved2;
        public ushort wReserved3;
        public Int32 data01;
        public Int32 data02;
    }

    private Variant _variant;

    private IntPtr _variantPtr;

    public ComVariant(int variantPtr) : this(new IntPtr(variantPtr))
    {
    }

    public ComVariant(IntPtr variantPtr)
    {
        _variant = (Variant)Marshal.PtrToStructure(variantPtr, typeof(Variant));
        _variantPtr = variantPtr;
    }

    public VarEnum Vt
    {
        get
        {
            return (VarEnum)_variant.vt;
        }
        set
        {
            _variant.vt = (ushort)value;
        }
    }

    public object Object
    {
        get
        {
            return Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(_variantPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

then if you are accessing a VT_UNKNOWN pointing to a COM interface object instance, just

```
var variant = new ComVariant(variantPtr);
var stream = variant.Object as IStream; // will not be null if type is correct
var obj = variant.Object as IObj; // in general...
```

will do the trick, but pay attention not to use a newly allocated VARIANT and giving its ownership to the .NET implementation without deallocating it somewhere...

For more complex code **you might read** [this article](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/using-variants-in-managed-code-part-1/) which also talks about memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back. Sooner or later, we want the actual data in the VARIANT. A VARIANT is just a holder for meaningful data. Suppose we converted the VARIANT to some sort of Object in C# that had the variant type and some raw buffer under the .NET hood (e.g. .NET strings can expose the raw buffer). At that point, the VARIANT type would need to be determined from the object and the raw data converted or cast to the data type specified by the variant, and then create a new Object e.g. string/int/etc. from the raw data.

So, rather than worry about passing the VARIANT to C#, look at the variant data type and convert it in C++ to the actual data type and pass that to C#.

For example, if the VARIANT type is VT_INT, then get the int from the variant and can use something like:

```
VARIANT var;

Int^ returnInt = gcnew Int(var.intVal);
```

returnInt can be returned as an Out parameter from a C++ function in a C++ dll that can be called from C#. The C++ dll needs to use /clr option.

Function would look like:-

```
void ThisFunctionReturnsAnInt(Runtime::InteropServices::OutAttribute Int^ % returnIntValue)
{

    VARIANT var;
    Int^ returnInt = gcnew Int(var.intVal);
}
```

Can use similar approach for other data types. It's only natural, a VARIANT of VT_INT is really just like an int, it's not as if there's some major conversion going on, you're just taking the actual value out of the VARIANT at the time when you're interested in it as you would if you were passing a straight integer value from C++ to C#. You would still need to do the gcnew anyway.