# How to translate a C++ method with VARIANT to C# without VARIANT?

Tags: c#, c++, variant

I've never worked with variants in C++. But I'm maintaining code from old C++ projects. Part of it is to translate it or part of it into C#.

I found methods that use variants. I want to "kill" any variant use in a new project version. Can someone help me out on how? Based on this example maybe? Also I'm not a C++ expert. I would like to know what this method is doing (Obviously converting variant to byte array. But how exactly? Where is the data etc.?)

**(Example) Method:**

```
protected bool ConvertVariantToByteArray(VARIANT vtData, int lCount, BYTE[] pArray)
{
    if (vtData.vt != (VARENUM.VT_ARRAY | VARENUM.VT_UI1))
        return false;
    BYTE[] pSafeArrayData;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayAccessData(vtData.parray, (void**) &pSafeArrayData)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    long lLbound;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayGetLBound(vtData.parray, 1, &lLbound)))
    {
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(vtData.parray);
        return false;
    }
    long lUbound;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayGetUBound(vtData.parray, 1, &lUbound)))
    {
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(vtData.parray);
        return false;
    }
    if (lCount < lUbound - lLbound + 1)
    {
        lCount = lUbound - lLbound + 1;
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(vtData.parray);
        return false;
    }
    for (long i = lLbound; i < lUbound + 1; ++i)
    {
        *pArray++ = *pSafeArrayData++;
    }
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(vtData.parray);
    lCount = lUbound - lLbound + 1;
    return true;
}
```

**Larger context:**

The application reads/writes via Falcon library to/from EIB/KNX bus. Seems the data passed to/from the bus is of VARIANT data type.

Comment: Variants are used with COM objects. If you are using COM, then you may have to use variants. What's the larger context of your question?

Comment: Did you have a look here? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806733/variant-datatype-of-c-into-c-sharp

Comment: It mostly corrupts memory, the caller does not have good odds at guessing at the required size of pArray.  Do not use it.  Converting a variant to byte[] in C# is trivial, just cast it.

Answer (score 1):

`VARIANT` is a COM thing rather than a C++ thing. You may not need to translate this method verbatim if you are moving away from variants.

A `VARIANT` can stores (alomst) anything, including other `VARIANTS`. The code you have shown converts a `VARIANT` to an array of bytes.

The array has a lower and upper bound (`lbound` and `ubound` in this sample) - they do no need to run from 0 up. The `for` loop is copying the data into the array.

You can call COM from C#, so may not need to translate the code.